Window's unusual behabior on Xorg
in ubuntu i'm facing a problem :
Problem is : when i switch to another window and spin mouse scroll  there is  suddenly lagged the scrolling and  suddenly
the scroll bar  to to the bottom of the ber of the window  ,
problem is to the display may be after switching window suddenly window behave like a spin big more the scroll of the mouse  : problem is happenning only Xorg not Wayland 

is there anyone here to help me to this problem ? 


please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly.
